# Is launching an activity in substitution for a dialog bad practice?

Tags: android

Personally, I like to open a new activity instead of a dialog because I can control the design  easier (such as the layout, different window options, size). Plus I feel it's much simpler to handle all of the component's listeners and such. But is there any benefit to running a dialog  instead of an activity? Is it faster and less memory exhausting?

Comment: I don't know the performance benefits (if any) however I can say that one of the main reasons I use Activity instead of dialog is how the behavior is handled on state change... e.g. screen orientation change. An exception is thrown even for the most basic dialog when the screen rotates.

Comment: Have you thought about setting the `Activity`'s `theme` to `dialog` (in the Android Manifest)? This will launch the `Activity` as a dialog. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: I have plenty of Dialogs that rotate correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you can create a custom Dialog to look basically however you want. However, as a direct answer to your question, the only drawbacks that I can think of are a) the original activity is now in an onStop state which means it could be killed, and b) You are using more resources to add a whole activity, instead of a dialog. That being said, there is a time and a place for everything.

Comment: I've never thought about onStop being an issue but that's a good point. In general, I use an activity for more robust dialogs and dialog for basic ones. But it sounds like that isn't too big of an issue.